# dropping and adding subscription only picking up new article on some subscribers

Tags: sql-server-2012, high-availability, transactional-replication

I have used the following script to drop aand re-add a table from a subscription so I could move replace the ntext fields with nvarchar(max) columns. the script worked fine, but when I ran the snapshot agent, it generated the new snapshot with 1 article, but only delivered to 2 of the 4 subscribing servers. They all have a subscription in the script. Can anyone suggest why this would be ?

The only thing that is different with those servers is that they also have a AV group installed on them. Could a bug in SQL 2012 be preventing the replication process working properly ??

```
sys.sp_dropsubscription @publication = 'statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @article = 'pgeDataLocation_tbl', -- sysname
  @subscriber = 'CHICAGO', -- sysname
  @destination_db = 'MLT-Replicated' -- sysname
GO
sys.sp_dropsubscription @publication = 'statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @article = 'pgeDataLocation_tbl', -- sysname
  @subscriber = 'SURVIVOR', -- sysname
  @destination_db = 'MLT-Replicated' -- sysname
GO
sys.sp_dropsubscription @publication = 'statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @article = 'pgeDataLocation_tbl', -- sysname
  @subscriber = 'KINKS', -- sysname
  @destination_db = 'MLT-Replicated' -- sysname
GO
sys.sp_dropsubscription @publication = 'statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @article = 'pgeDataLocation_tbl', -- sysname
  @subscriber = 'BLONDIE', -- sysname
  @destination_db = 'MLT-Replicated' -- sysname
GO



sys.sp_droparticle @publication = 'statics BLOB tables',
  @article = 'pgeDataLocation_tbl'
GO



---  table changes



sys.sp_addarticle @publication ='statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @article = 'pgeDataLocation_tbl', -- sysname
  @source_object = N'pgeDataLocation_tbl', -- nvarchar(386)
  @destination_table = 'pgeDataLocation_tbl' -- sysname
  GO
  sys.sp_addsubscription @publication = 'statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @subscriber = 'CHICAGO', -- sysname
  @destination_db = 'MLT-Replicated' -- sysname
  GO
  sys.sp_addsubscription @publication = 'statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @subscriber = 'SURVIVOR', -- sysname
  @destination_db = 'MLT-Replicated' -- sysname
  GO
    sys.sp_addsubscription @publication = 'statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @subscriber = 'KINKS', -- sysname
  @destination_db = 'MLT-Replicated' -- sysname
  GO
    sys.sp_addsubscription @publication = 'statics BLOB tables', -- sysname
  @subscriber = 'PINKFLOYD', -- sysname
  @destination_db = 'MLT-Replicated' -- sysname
  GO
```

Comment: Have you monitored the server when the snapshot is delivered to the servers in this group? Does AV actually do something?